# object object in antd input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-select, antd

Any idea how to get rid of [object object] inside of antd input, it seems that inside map option i have < br /> which is causing this, how to have that 
 inside map but not have it inside input ? inside map it will cause them to come under eachother thats reason i'm using it there. So any idea how to not have it in input ?

```js
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Button, AutoComplete } from "antd";
import { CloseOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const EventsSection = () => {
  const autoControl = React.createRef();
  const defaultOptions = [
    { value: "1", text: "Nicholas" },
    { value: "2", text: "Alex" },
    { value: "3", text: "Putin" },
    { value: "4", text: "Biden" },
    { value: "5", text: "Peka" },
    { value: "6", text: "James" },
    { value: "7", text: "James" }
  ];
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(defaultOptions);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({ value: "", text: "" });
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(true);

  const { Option } = AutoComplete;

  const changeHandler = (_, option) => {
    const value = option.children;
    setSelectedOption({ value: option.key, text: value });
  };

  function handleClick() {
    console.log(`value: ${selectedOption.value}, text: ${selectedOption.text}`);
  }

  function onClear() {
    setSelectedOption({ value: "", text: "" });
  }

  function onFocusChange() {
    if (!dropdownOpen) setDropdownOpen(true);
  }

  function onSearch(value) {
    setOptions(
      defaultOptions.filter((f) =>
        f.text.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {/* when found in search i want this button take to  'onChange' address also*/}
      <button disabled={!selectedOption.value} onClick={handleClick}>
        click me when found in search
      </button>
      <AutoComplete
        ref={autoControl}
        open={dropdownOpen}
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        placeholder="Search..."
        listHeight={220}
        onSearch={(e) => onSearch(e)}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        value={selectedOption.text}
        onFocus={onFocusChange}
        onBlur={() => setDropdownOpen(false)}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <Option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.text}
            <br />
            {option.value}

          </Option>
        ))}
      </AutoComplete>
      <Button
        disabled={!selectedOption.value}
        onClick={onClear}
        type="primary"
        icon={<CloseOutlined />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EventsSection;
```

Comment: any idea here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try filter out object element from your input field value since it is an array

```
const changeHandler = (_, option) => {
  const value = option.children.filter((each) => typeof each !== 'object');
  setSelectedOption({ value: option.key, text: value });
};
```

Comment: Could you tell what is job of this ”_,” ?

Comment: this is used to replace the unused parameter of `onChange` handler

Comment: What unused? and is it used just on antd or we can use it on any onchange ?

Comment: `onChange?: (value: ValueType, option: OptionsType[number] | OptionsType) => void;` as you see in `selectProps` the first parameter is `value` which is unused, so you may replace it with `_`

Comment: This onchange is defined in antd